# presto/athena get next minute from current timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

How to get next minute from `current_timestamp` in presto/athena

Eg.

1. 2021-07-27 12:29:52.951 UTC -> 2021-07-27 12:30:00.000 UTC
2. 2021-07-27 12:29:25.951 UTC -> 2021-07-27 12:30:00.000 UTC

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in function for that, but you can do it by adding 1 minute to the timestamp and then using [`date_trunc`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html?highlight=date_trunc#date_trunc) to round down to the nearest minute:

```sql
WITH data(ts) AS (
    VALUES
        TIMESTAMP '2021-07-27 12:29:52.951 UTC',
        TIMESTAMP '2021-07-27 12:29:25.951 UTC'
)
SELECT ts, date_trunc('minute', ts + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)
FROM data
```

=>

```
             ts              |            _col1
-----------------------------+-----------------------------
 2021-07-27 12:29:52.951 UTC | 2021-07-27 12:30:00.000 UTC
 2021-07-27 12:29:25.951 UTC | 2021-07-27 12:30:00.000 UTC
(2 rows)
```